# How do I build the right *.SO library for Android?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I wrote a small Dynamic library for Android in `C++`

When trying to open the library, an error occurs:

```
dlopen failed: library "libFunct.so" not found ndk_StdJni_set State Code__I.in__
```

How can I fix it, apparently me need to add some header file from NDK?

NDK has never been used, the first time I'm trying to write a Library for android,
In pure `C`, just a couple of functions

**NDK(JNI) I don't need it and don't intend to use it.**

Comment: I don't think you need to add some random header but rather put libFunct.so in the correct place on the filesystem

Comment: Brother - Thank you very much, you wrote everything correctly. Fixed the PATH and it connects.